# Copy comman in p4python with Perforce

Tags: python-3.6, perforce, p4python

For branching I from a certain CL and have it as a changelist I realized that Perforce uses the copy keyword. I'm tryin to use the same keyword but getting an error saying that the options are invalid. Following is my code:

```
result = self.p4.run("copy","-c" + change_List,"-F", Path_1+"/...@"+ CL, Path_2+"/...")
```

am I doing something wrong? Can anyone explain to me what the wrong part of my code is?

Comment: What are the values of all those variables?

Comment: Also, what specifically is the error message you get?  Have you tried running the same command from the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

See the usage info for `p4 copy`:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help copy

    copy -- Copy one set of files to another

    p4 copy [options] fromFile[rev] toFile
    p4 copy [options] -b branch [-r] [toFile[rev] ...]
    p4 copy [options] -b branch -s fromFile[rev] [toFile ...]
    p4 copy [options] -S stream [-P parent] [-F] [-r] [toFile[rev] ...]

        options: -c changelist# -f -n -v -m max -q
```

There is no form of the command that takes multiple file arguments **and** a `-F` flag.  The `-F` flag is only applicable if you're using streams, since its purpose is to allow you to override the defined "flow" of the two streams.

Comment: What I am trying to branch from a main-branch, with a specific CL, to release branch. I saw from the perforce command window that it runs this command. if I want to branch from branch a (which normally is the main stream) to a release branch isn't copy a good option?

Comment: For creating a new branch it's more efficient to use `populate`, but if you don't care about runtime, `copy` and `integrate` are about equally good.  In any case, you need to use the command correctly (i.e. don't pass random nonsense as args) for it to work.  :)